# Debugging servlets from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss7.x

In Eclipse I can select a servlet from a web application, and choose "Run As -> Run on Server" from the context menu.
One minor problem is that a browser is opened with a wrong url.
For example, I have written a servlet similar to:

```
package mypackage;

@WebServlet("/append")
public class AppendTest extends HttpServlet {
@Override public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) ... 
...
}
```

then I can test it in a browser with a URL similar to:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/mywebapp/append

But when I choose to run the servlet as explained above, the browser is directed to:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/mywebapp/servlet/mypackage/AppendTest

Although this is a minor problem for testing the application, in fact this issue does not let me debug it, since when I select "Debug As -> Debug on Server", the same problem happens, and the debugger stops after the 404 http status answer (if I correct the URL after the 404 status, the debugger is not active anymore).

The servlet container I am using is JBoss.

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**

I was not able to debug since the server was not correctly configured in Eclipse (configured as managed externally instead of by Eclipse, thanks for the hint @CarlosGavidia).

This apparently solves the biggest problem. If someone knows how to make Eclipse to open the right URL of the servlet at once instead of myself annoyingly correcting the url every time I run/debug it I will be thankful.

I am starting to think that this is an Eclipse bug. If I explicitly declare the URL pattern in the web.xml then eclipse will use the correct url. That means that the value of the `WebServlet` annotation indicating that URL when writing the servlet class is just ignored by eclipse when running/debugging the application :(

Comment: Ignore the wrong URL Eclipse uses and use the correct one.

Comment: @Carlos, as I said in the question the problem is that I cannot debug the servlet like that: the debugger is not active after the 404 http status answer.

Comment: Change the URL in your Browser -use the correct one- and the Debugger should launch. If that's not happening, the problem is not your URL but your server settings.

Comment: the debugger is not active after receiving the 404 status message. After correcting the address in the browser the servlet is correctly invoked, but the debugger is not active anymore. 
As far as I understand the debugger should be active only until receiving a complete answer from the servlet, or am I wrong about that ?

Comment: @Carlos I found the problem, indeed the server was not correctly configured. Thanks. I updated the question with my finding.

Comment: If it works like it does with Tomcat, the entire server's being debugged, not just the one Servlet.

Comment: yes, I think this is how debugging of servlets works in JBoss. I start the server in debug mode (then as you say is like the entire server is being debugged) and then I just evaluate the servlet and the breakpoints are captured. afaik this is the way to do it.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  However, servlets in one project all launch with the right URL, which servlets from another project launch with the wrong URL.  I can't find any config differences.  It is the same server instance.  All servlets work.  It is just a launch problem.  Help?